# Increasing the width of a block of text in the book class

Tags: width, books, text

The following code gives example pages from a style of book.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{book}
    \setlength\headheight{0cm}

    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{headbgcolor}{green!50!blue!70}
    \setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\enskip#1}{}}
    \fancyhf{}

    \fancyhead[LE]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{
    \colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}\enskip}}\hspace*{1em}}%
    {\itshape\leftmark}\hspace*{1em}\headrulefill%
    }
    \fancyhead[RO]{%
    \mbox{}\headrulefill \hspace*{1em}{\itshape\leftmark}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace*{1em}\colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\enskip  \bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}}}%
     }
     \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

     \def\headrulefill{\leaders\hrule width 0pt height 3pt depth -2.8pt \hfill}

     \usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

     \fancypagestyle{plain}{
     \fancyhf{}
     \fancyhead[LE]{%
     \makebox[0pt][r]{
     \colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\bfseries \textcolor{white}{\thepage}\enskip}}\hspace*{1em}}%
{\itshape\leftmark}\hspace*{1em}\headrulefill%
     }
     \fancyhead[RO]{%
     \mbox{}\headrulefill \hspace*{1em}{\itshape\leftmark}%
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
     \hspace*{1em}\colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\enskip\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}}}%
     }
     }
     \usepackage{mathptmx} 
     \begin{document}
     \blinddocument
     \end{document}
```

I was wondering if there is any way to increase the width of the blocks of text in this document class in the direction as indicated by arrows in the image below: [image] I've tried to use commands from the geometry package and \setlength{\rightmargin}{...}  but to no avail. Any help appreciated. I have a feeling it will be something obvious I've missed...

Comment: Have you tried the `width` option of `geometry`? `\usepackage[width=16cm]{geometry}`.  By the way, you should not write `\setlength\headheight{0cm}` since you obviously have a heading.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
\setlength\headheight{0cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}
```

you should better use package `geometry`. From your screenshot I guess that the values topmargin `tmargin=2cm`, rightmargin `rmargin=3cm` and textwidth `width=14cm` are the values you need. If not chage them for your needs.

So adding the command

```
\usepackage[rmargin=3cm,tmargin=2cm,width=14cm]{geometry} % <===========
```

in your preamble should do what you want.

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

%\setlength\headheight{0cm}
%\setlength{\topmargin}{-1.5cm}

\usepackage[rmargin=3cm,tmargin=2cm,width=14cm]{geometry} % <===========

\usepackage{xcolor}
    \colorlet{headbgcolor}{green!50!blue!70}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter:\enskip#1}{}}
    \fancyhf{}

    \fancyhead[LE]{%
    \makebox[0pt][r]{
    \colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}\enskip}}\hspace*{1em}}%
    {\itshape\leftmark}\hspace*{1em}\headrulefill%
    }
    \fancyhead[RO]{%
    \mbox{}\headrulefill \hspace*{1em}{\itshape\leftmark}%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \hspace*{1em}\colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\enskip  \bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}}}%
     }
     \renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

     \def\headrulefill{\leaders\hrule width 0pt height 3pt depth -2.8pt \hfill}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text

     \fancypagestyle{plain}{
     \fancyhf{}
     \fancyhead[LE]{%
     \makebox[0pt][r]{
     \colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][r]{\bfseries \textcolor{white}{\thepage}\enskip}}\hspace*{1em}}%
{\itshape\leftmark}\hspace*{1em}\headrulefill%
     }
     \fancyhead[RO]{%
     \mbox{}\headrulefill \hspace*{1em}{\itshape\leftmark}%
     \makebox[0pt][l]{%
     \hspace*{1em}\colorbox{headbgcolor}{\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\enskip\bfseries\textcolor{white}{\thepage}}}}%
     }
     }
\usepackage{mathptmx} 


\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

I get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]